# SharePoint 2013 Workflow missing from site template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, site-template

I created a site in SPD2013 that contains various lists, workflows, etc...
The site has a number of SharePoint 2010 workflows and a 2013 workflow.  I created a site template from this existing site and tried creating a new site from the template.  For some reason, everything was included except for the single 2013 workflow from the original site.  According to Microsoft, workflows should be included in the site template, so how come this one workflow was missing.  I know you can save a 2013 workflow as a WSP by itself and upload it as a solution but I want to make sure that I don't create extra steps in the process that are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check Include Content when you save your template, otherwise the workflow will not be saved within the template.